# Merge all files into a exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exe

How do I merge all of my project from VS2010 into a single exe file?

My application has a solution with 4 project and the IT architecture is N-tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ilmerge http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx if your application is .NET